# How to inherit the properties from a class when using CSS Modules?

Tags: inheritance, css-modules, react-css-modules

I am making a collapsible sidebar, for that I have 2 classes:

```
.sidebar {
    background-color: #f5fafa;
    width: 5vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.sidebar__expanded {
    background-color: #f5fafa;
    width: 10vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```

As you can see, every property is same except the width of the two, so I want to inherit the common properties from the .sidebar . How to do that when using CSS Modules ? I have tried using the `inherit` and the `composes` keyword but none of them seem to work , the terminal says property value expected in both. How to do that?

Thank you so much in advance!

I have tried using the `inherit` and the `composes` keyword but none of them seem to work , the terminal says property value expected in both. How to do that?

Comment: Please let me know even if you are unsure about it, I am eager to optimize my CSS since it's a very big project.